# Enlarge partition on SD card

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

I have followed [Cloning an SD card onto a larger SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/460657/cloning-an-sd-card-onto-a-larger-sd-card) to clone a 2G SD card to a 32G SD card, and the file system is ext4. However, on the 32G SD card I only can see 2G space available. Is there a way to maximize it out? Here is the output of `fdisk`:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32026656768 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 30543 cylinders, total 62552064 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e015a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32      147455       73712    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          147456     3994623     1923584   83  Linux
```

I want to make `/dev/sdb2` use up the remaining space. I try `resize2fs /dev/sdb` after `dd`, but get message below:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Now I use gparted to resize the sd card, and **it works**. I think it's possible to do this in command line. In my example, you should umount `/dev/sdb2` first, then `resize2fs /dev/sdb2` I guess. At least in gparted GUI I need to umount `/dev/sdb2` first.

**Edit 2**

Reboot will cause "init  not found" error. Even if I specify `init` path, it doesn't find `/root/dev/console` then kernel panic. Error message below:

```
/init: line 352: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sdb` is the device node pointing to the entire hard drive, and it starts at the first sector of the HDD. You need to point `resize2fs` to the specific **partition** you want to resize (apparently, in your case, `/dev/sdb2`).

FYI, using the console is not necessary if you have a graphical desktop. Just install `gparted` (you didn't indicate your Linux distro, so I don't know if it's available or, if so, what steps to install it). It will provide a user-friendly way to do this. You could also probably do it with the `palimpsest` Disk Utility on modern OSes.

Comment: Because I am using a virtual machine, I prefer to using command line rather than GUI. ;-) `resize2fs /dev/sdb2` shows me: "The filesystem is already 1923584 blocks long.  Nothing to do!". I guess I need to modify partition table first?

Comment: I'm having this problem myself, but this answer isn't working. `resize2fs /dev/sdb2` on an *un*mounted filesystem (after resizing with `parted` still produces "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2")