# Cloning an SD card onto a larger SD card - exFAT

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, dd, exfat

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and attempting to clone the SD card (128G) from my Android phone to a larger one (256G) for more capacity, without losing the file structure referencing my phone apps use.

I followed this thread:

[Cloning an SD card onto a larger SD card](https://superuser.com/questions/460657/cloning-an-sd-card-onto-a-larger-sd-card)

and tried everything suggested, however as my card is exFAT formatted to match the original, like the other commenters I have been unable to retain the full partition with available empty space on the new card.

Gparted sees the full partition (238G) and says "121.61 GiB of unallocated space within the partition". Both Disks and Nemo say the new card is 98.1% full (which is really just the cloned partition of course). Nothing yet seems able to modify the size of the exFAT partition, or free up the unallocated space.

When I used the dd command to clone the original partition (sudo dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdb1) it also seems to have carried the partition size information, and left the unallocated space unavailable.

Maybe I should try a different formatting option for the new card, if exFAT is so unchangeable?

Any help fixing this would be GREATLY appreciated! :-)

Comment: Wouldn't a simple file level copy work? Just do a fresh format and rsync it over

Comment: Thanks, let's find out! ;-D Total noob here, looking for rsync syntax now!

Comment: The alternative to doing a file level copy (which is probably the right solution) would be to find a tool to expand the exfat filesystem (like resizexfat instead of resize2fs) .  However, I don't know if that exists.  Or see if windows can resize it.

Comment: Thanks so much both, the rsync did work to copy everything intact, I just still had some bludgeoning to do through my Android apps to get them to see the files (audio in particular)....it's worked well enough for my purposes anyway! Cheers! :-)